# Meeting room and other resources in Outlook/Exchange?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, resources

In the Outlook setup we have at work, we can book meetings including resources like meeting rooms.

However, we have to remember to manually set the meeting rooms as "resource" in the meeting planner.

Does this mean the resource have been wrongly set up? Is there a way for us to set up these resources to be automatically flagged as resources when we plan meetings, since we forget to do this about half the time.

Comment: We have the exact same issue, 4 out of 10 meetings are booked with the room as 'To' not 'Resource'.... Found any solutions/improvements?

Answer (score 0):

Resource Mailboxes were added in Exchange 2007 and are also in Exchange 2010.  If you are running Exchange 2007 or 2010, your messaging department should have created them as resource mailboxes or converted them during the upgrade process from Exchange 2003.  Before Exchange 2007, they were just ordinary mailboxes and you must manually change them in Outlook.

More information on Resource Mailboxes in Exchange 2010 can be found here - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124374.aspx and for Exchange 2007 here - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124374(EXCHG.80).aspx